# Are Linux socket file descriptors generally suitable for hashing

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, hash

I am programming a Linux multi-user server, and each connection accepted returns an `int` containing the socket file descriptor for that connection. I also have one `UserConnection` object corresponding to each connection. I am using a hash table (C++ STL `unordered_map<int, UserConnection>`) to store key-value pairs of socket file descriptors (keys) and `UserConnection` objects (values).

Is it safe to put socket file descriptors as keys in a hash table? Is there any pattern in Linux's socket number allocation that might not work well with the hashing function?

Comment: Assuming you remove the key when the socket closes (ideally, just before, to avoid race conditions if you close a socket and another thread opens a socket with the same fd), I don't see any obvious issues.

Comment: Good call: thanks! I've changed UserConnection and moved the socket closing to the destructor so that it is done only when I call unordered_map::erase on the key in the ConnectionManager class.

Comment: You may as well prebuild your table of integer values used for descriptors to hashes. There's no need to hash all of them on the fly. It also seems like a simple sparse vector would work well, too. A more interesting application may be... A unique connection is the 4-tuple `{source IP, source port, destination IP, destination port}`. Using a hash table and digesting the 4-tuple is probably more suitable to participate. Finally, you probably need to key the hash to avoid potential DoS'es. I believe the [kernel is switching to SipHash](https://lwn.net/Articles/711167/) for such applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [manual page for open(2)](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/open.2.html) explictly states that the lowest unused  file descriptor is assigned to the new file descriptor:

> The file descriptor returned by a successful call will be the
>   lowest-numbered file descriptor not currently open for the process.

Similar verbiage appears to be missing from `socket(2)`, but I think this is a fairly safe assumption -- that the same applies to socket as well.

It then follows that creating sockets will result in monotonically increasing file descriptors, for the new sockets, which will be reused at the first opportunity. As such, this is the ideal use case for hashing.

Comment: "Hashing" may imply that you apply some hash function to the fd. However, libstdc++ applies no hash function to the integer. It simply maps it modulo the number of buckets.